# Show a page before user approves the application

Tags: facebook

I was wondering if it was possible to show the user a page of my application before they approved the app.  Something like a splash screen that wouldn't need to use any of the user's data.

This is an example:  https://apps.facebook.com/288033751224625/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's totally up to you at what point you ask for permissions from the user. You are not limited to a single "splash" screen either. In theory you could have an entire app that never asked for any persmissions. In general, you should let users look around the app and only ask for permissions when you need specific data about them.